# Using reflection to identify if the error thrown matches expected error

Tags: java, reflection

I need to write a simple code tester program, but I got stuck comparing the given error class with the test expected class. I am supposed to use reflection in this exercise.

I have my code testing class:

```
public class TestRunner {

    private String result = "";

    public void runTests(List<String> testClassNames) {
        for (String testClassName : testClassNames) {
            Class<?> clazz;
            try {
                clazz = Class.forName(testClassName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No such class.");
            }
            Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {
                if (method.getAnnotation(MyTest.class) != null) {
                    if (testClassName.equals("reflection.tester.ExampleTests1")) {
                        result += method.getName() + "() - ";
                        ExampleTests1 instance = new ExampleTests1();
                        try {
                            // if null, result = OK
                            method.invoke(instance);
                            result += "OK\n";
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                            // if error is caught result = FAILED
                            result += "FAILED\n";
                        }
                    } else {
                        // the second class. should only return "OK" if the error is implemented from the exception class
                        result += method.getName() + "() - ";
                        ExampleTests2 instance = new ExampleTests2();
                        try {
                            method.invoke(instance);
                            result += "FAILED\n";
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                            Throwable original = e.getCause();
                            Object expected = method.getReturnType();
                            if (original.getClass().isAssignableFrom(expected.getClass())) {
                                result += "OK\n";
                            } else {
                                result += "FAILED\n";
                            }
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                            result += "ERROR\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also  have two test classes. In the first one there is only one rule, if the test won't throw an exception the test should pass, and it is working. The second class is more complicated. If the thrown error class is implemented or same to the expected error class then the test should pass and OK should be added to the result. Currently my code won't catch RunTimeException at all and moves to the last catch block. How can I fix this?

I will also add the test class for more information.

```
public class ExampleTests2 {

    @MyTest(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void test3() {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @MyTest(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void test4() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @MyTest(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void test5() {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @MyTest(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void test6() {
    }

    public void helperMethod() {
    }


}
```

test3() and test5() should pass, test4() and test6() should fail, helperMethod() won't be checked because I only need to use the tests with @MyTest annotation.

Comment: JUnit has an assertThrows method that checks that an Exception is thrown

Comment: @DavidTejuosho how can I use this in my last else block?

Comment: The purpose of JUnit is not that you reimplement it. But if you want to continue on this road, you have to use `method.getAnnotation(MyTest.class).expected()` to get the value of the annotation. Obviously, `method.getReturnType()` is not the same thing. But there are so many things wrong in your code, I don’t know where to start. Exceptions thrown in the method are encapsulated in the `InvocationTargetException`, for example, so `catch (RuntimeException e) {…}` is the wrong place to handle this. Further, when no exception occurred but one was expected, it should also be handled as FAILED.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit has an assertThrows method that checks that an Exception is thrown. It has a method signature of

```java
static <T extends Throwable> assertThrows​(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable){}
```

Here's the documentation: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)

and here's how JUnit implements it:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/main/junit-jupiter-api/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/api/AssertThrows.java

Comment: Op tries to implement JUnit themself, so a link to the actual implementation might be more helpful.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn noted